# Php remove special chracter from from last charcters of string

Tags: php, string, replace

I have sets of array string .. which contain special character in last place as well as between them. I want to remove only special character from last place.

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $string);
```

I know I can use replace function to remove all special characters but I don't want to remove special characters between string. I only want to remove special character from last position. Sorry for my bad English..

```
hope,
 all" 
inthe. 
world" 
to-the. 
world" 
some-thing"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/rtrim) if the special characters you want to remove are known before-hand:

```
$string = rtrim($string, ',".');
```

The second parameter describes the list of characters that should be removed.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/97060)

---

If the special characters aren't known, then you could use a regex solution. The below `preg_replace()` statement will remove any character that's not a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, or a hyphen (`-`) or a single-quote (`'`):

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\-\']$/', '', $str);
```

**Explanation:**

- `[^\w-\']` - match a single character **not** present in the list

  - `\w` - any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
  - `\-` - the literal character `-`
  - `\'` - the literal character `'`
- `$`  - "end of line" anchor - used to assert position at end of the string

Answer (score 1):

This should work (note addition of `$` in the regex):

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']$/', '', $string);
```

The `$` matches the end of the line, so only when the preceding match is the last character, the regular expression will match.